# Delay inside Macro - Is It Possible in Vim Macros to Create a Delay Between Commands?

Tags: macro

**Does something like this exist?:**

```lua
let @p = "0D:!ping -c1 8.8.8.8\<CR>"<SLEEP 1 SECOND>"\<CR>iJust pinged a DNS Server\<ESC>"
```

---

- And let me read the `ping` result. So things like `gs` are **not** possible...

Comment: Is there a reason to not do `:read !ping …` instead?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Why should I use the read command? I don't want to write the output of the ping command... Or am I missing something?^^

Comment: You could then do `:read !ping`, `gs`, `:delete` or something similar (plus it would be in your buffer, so you could also just show the results and edit as desired).

Comment: Ahhh interesting approach. I am gonna try that one out^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your requirement of being able to read the output, I'd move the delay into the shell command:

```
:let @p = "0D:!ping -c1 8.8.8.8 ; sleep 1\<CR>iJust pinged a DNS Server\<Esc>"
```

I don't think there's any other way of introducing a delay into the middle of Vim's `:!` command: control doesn't return to the macro until after it's completed and the output has been removed from the screen.

Alternative solutions would be to use D. Ben Knoble's [suggestion of reading the output into the buffer itself](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/42694/delay-inside-macro-is-it-possible-in-vim-macros-to-create-a-delay-between-comm#comment76508_42694) and then removing it again *after* the delay, or to move everything into a function where you can do whatever you like and then (if necessary) call this from the macro. This would be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `gs` command to introduce a delay.  This command can be prefixed with a count to specify the number of seconds.  Refer to the [help page](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#gs) for more information. For example, to introduce a 2 second delay, you can use the following:

```
let @p = "0D:!ping -c1 8.8.8.8\<CR>2gsiJust pinged a DNS Server\<Esc>"
```

Comment: No this doesn't work. I obviously want to read the `ping` Prompt. So before the `<CR>` not after^^ But thanks for showing me that I can replace `^M` with `\<ESC>` :)

Comment: Why is your answer getting upvoted?? It does **not** work >:(

Comment: @Pixelbog I'm guessing it's because it answers the general requirement of how to introduce a delay into macro playback, and because you edited in the bit about wanting to read the output later.

Comment: @Rich I thought that it is self explanatory that I want to read the output of my ping command :(